# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'routes'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm following Cory House's [pluralsight course](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=react-redux-react-router-es6&author=cory-house&name=react-redux-react-router-es6-m4&clip=5&mode=live) on building React in ES6. Unfortunately I'm stuck on one of the first couple steps, setting up the basic components.

In the console I see the following error message:

```
Warning: [react-router] Location "/" did not match any routes
```

If I look in my dev server I see the following

> ERROR in ./src/index.js
>
> Warning: [react-router] Location "/" did not match any routes

Then below that I see that eslint has kicked out the following error:

> C:\Projects\es6react\src\index.js (1/0)
>
> ✖  5:9  routes not found in './routes'  import/named

So this *should* be pretty straightforward. However, looking at my directory structure, `index.js` file and `routes.js` nothing stands out... even after about 30 minutes.

**index.js**

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import {routes} from './routes';
import './styles/styles.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

render(
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route,IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';
import HomePage from './components/home/HomePage';
import AboutPage from './components/about/AboutPage';

export default(
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="about" component={AboutPage}/>
    </Route>
);
```

**Directory structure**

[image]

And just in case my `scripts` section from my `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "babel-node tools/startMessage.js",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel open:src lint:watch test:watch",
    "open:src":"babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/esw webpack.config.* src tools",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "test":"mocha --reporter progress tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.test.js\"",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using default export, you need to import it as default (without curly braces):

```
import routes from './routes';
```

On the other hand you can use named export and import it by name:

```
// index.js
export const routes = ...

// routes.js
import {routes} from './routes';
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing default export from `routes.js` file not named export, and importing it as named export.

Use this:

```
import routes from './routes';     //remove {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used 'export default' in routes.js, this means that to import it you need to use:

import routes from "./routes";

In your code you have used {routes} which would import when exported without the default.